# Los estamos esperando - why not Les estamos esperando?

Tags: gramática

We are waiting for them. 
Los estamos esperando

However, isn't the indirect object "them", hence shouldnt the pronoun be les?
eg.  Les estamos esperando  ?  Esta confuso! :)

Would this be correct?
Les estamos esperando a ellos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negativo. Se trata de un **objeto directo** ya que '(a) ellos' es en este caso un objeto que recibe directamente la acción de esperar. Por lo tanto, es correcto el uso de **los**.

Lo que confunde es que es válido formular la pregunta '¿**A** quién?' para el verbo *esperar*. Si bien no está mal basarse en tal criterio como *ayuda*, lo cierto es que no son las preguntas '¿Qué/quién?' y '¿A qué/quién?' decisivas para reconocer respectivamente al objeto directo del indirecto.

Creo que lo más fácil es fijarse qué pronombre admite el verbo. Si admite *lo/los* sabemos que es objeto directo, y en cambio si admite *le/les* entonces es objeto indirecto. Para los no-nativos, supongo que con algo de práctica se puede aprender a reconocer el pronombre válido para un determinado verbo en una oración. Más detalladamente, [acá hay una explicación sobre cómo reconocer los objetos directos e indirectos.](https://ahorasipaso.com/leccion/objeto-directo-e-indirecto/)

**ANEXO**

¿Qué ocurre si optamos por '**les** esperamos'? Estaríamos incurriendo en lo que se conoce como [**leísmo**](https://www.rae.es/dpd/le%C3%ADsmo). Sólo en algunos casos se considera válido hacerlo, así que no pretendo desarrollar todo el tópico en cuestión. Pero dejo [el 'veredicto' de la RAE](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/1254349752294129664) respecto de tu pregunta inicial:

> Consultas de la semana | Referido a ustedes, ¿es «les esperamos» o «los esperamos»?

> Es preferible usar «los», pues ahí el pronombre es complemento directo, pero el uso de «les» sería admisible como **leísmo de cortesía**.

Comment: Thank you very much.I understand now. The word "them" is the direct object. Comparing these two sentences helped:
(1) We are waiting for them.
(2) We throw the ball to them.